# How to open a thread in MFC to run a cuda function?

Tags: multithreading, cuda, mfc

I now change my cuda program into an MFC project, I wrote the function of .cu as an interface function, So I can call it in MFC's dlg,Because I now use the UI thread call, I want to open a work thread to call, but failed.I am making AfxBeginThread, but it does not recognize my interface function.

I use vs2013, win7.
my interface function like this:

```
extern "C" float solveGPU(M_args Parameter_, double Mtime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [AfxBeginThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) use but you have to call yout function from a new function or a static method with he following prototype:

```
UINT __cdecl MyControllingFunction( LPVOID pParam );
```

like this:

```
UINT __cdecl SolveGPUThreadFunction( LPVOID pParam )
{
    YourDialogClass* pThis = (YourDialogClass*)(pParam);

    pThis->result= solveGPU(pThis->Parameter_, pThis->Mtime);
}
```

and pass `this` pointer of your dialog as `pParam` of `AfxBeginThread`:

```
CWinThread* pCUDAThread = AfxBeginThread(&SolveGPUThreadFunction, this);
```

But you can think about using the std::thread instead.

Comment: i try to use std::thread ,but i also meet some questions.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302074/type-traits1545-error-c2280